# NxN matrix in python with non-duplicate integers (in range [0:N-1]) in both rows AND columns

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, 2d

In python, how to create a matrix or 2D array of N x N such that :
[A] Each Row has non-duplicate integers from 0 : N-1
And [B] Each Column has non-duplicate integers from 0:N-1

Example :

```
 [[1 0 2]
  [2 1 0]
  [0 2 1]]
```

Comment: Can you show the code, you have so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: @RolandDeschain : The code that you provided works fine for rotating rows. Thanks. I have some constraints on the position of numbers that I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had a bit of a tinker with this question, this code seems to work

```
import numpy as np

N = 10

row = np.arange(N)
result = np.zeros((N, N))
for i in row:
    result[i] = np.roll(row, i)

print(result)
```

output:

```
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [9. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8.]
 [8. 9. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7.]
 [7. 8. 9. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]
 [6. 7. 8. 9. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0. 1. 2.]
 [2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0. 1.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0.]]
```

Ask away if you have any questions.